# How to add confirmation dialog

Tags: jsf-2

I want to add confirmation dialog befor editing a row or how to prompt user a confirmation befor any action.
which dialog should I use for below code.

```
<h:commandLink value="EditPage" action="#{countryBean.editCountryByCountryCode(true)}"  class="edit_icon" >
             <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{countryBean.editCountryId}" value="#{countryLang.countryCode}" />
             </h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A simple way, using a simple javascript:

```
<h:commandLink onclick="if (! confirm('Really want to do that?')) return false"
value="EditPage" action="#{countryBean.editCountryByCountryCode(true)}"  class="edit_icon" >
   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{countryBean.editCountryId}" value="#{countryLang.countryCode}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: The shorter "return confirm('Really want to do that?')" is also correct.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Primefaces Confirm dialog  `<p:confirm/>` for this purpose. You can find example showcase [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml).

Comment: but that is applicable for p:commandbutton only..can u provide examples for h:commandLink can be other then primeface.

Comment: If you don't want to use `primefaces` , then you can always have a choice to use `JQuery` if you are familiar with that.

Comment: What if I do not use primefaces and jQuery either?