# JSF Primefaces mobile confirmation dialog not working

Tags: jsf-2.2, primefaces-mobile

I am trying to add confirmation dialog in a dialog using primefaces mobile. I have tried these examples

```
<p:dialog id="main">
<h:form>

    <p:growl id="messages" />

    <p:commandButton value="Delete" onclick="confirmation.show()" type="button"/>

    <p:confirmDialog  message="Are you sure?" header="Confirmation" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" update="messages" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"
                    actionListener="#{buttonBean.destroyWorld}" />
        <p:commandButton value="Not" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />
    </p:confirmDialog>

</h:form>
</dialog>
```

When i am rendering the page the confirmation dialog is not rendered as dialog also the command buttons are listed.

When i keep confirm dialog in another form, its not invoking the dialog.

1. [JSF](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2732)
2. [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362983/how-to-add-confirmation-dialog)

I cannot get either of them to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We cannot help you when you don't include the exact code that you used any error message, expected results and actual results. Please edit your post with any and all relevant information. Don't put stuff like **Edit** or **Update** in your revised question when you do. This site has edit history, those who need to see differences can get the information from there.

Comment: @Anthon Added details

Comment: Please, PLEASE add a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, You won't find much help here. Also make sure, your example is working (you missed to close the `<p:dialog` correctly.).